# Build Array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Desired result: The result would be a function that builds an array of values from column B. The values are restricted by having the same value in column A. 'E.g. Column A value = 1 myArray = (0,1,2)' 'Column B Value = 2 myArray = (4,5,6,7,8)'

First time trying to use arrays in VBA and need help.  I have the following data in columns A and B in Excel:

```
A   B
1   0
1   1
1   2
2   4
2   5
2   6
2   7
2   8
3   9
3   10
3   11
4   12
4   15
4   18
```

I have the following VBA Code:

```
Function buildMyArray()

    Dim ARange as Range
    Dim B as Integer
    Dim myArrary as Variant

    For Each ARange In Sheets("SheetName").Range("B:B")
        If ARange.Value = 1 Then
            B = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ARange.Value, Sheets("SheetName").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
            myArray = Array(B)
        End If
    Next ARange

End Function
```

I am trying to build a function that will search column A for each instance of an integer (which I will eventually dynamically pass).  Then for each instance of that integer do a vlookup on the adjacent column (B).  I then want to create an array of the values from the lookup (in the above case (0,1,2)).

The above code is the closest I have gotten.  I get returned the first value in B (0) as the only value in the array.  I am reasonably confident this is because the array logic is in the If statement.  However, if I move it out of there I get compile errors.

Please help a novice learn.  Thanks.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're trying to do. Can you explain what you want the result to be in simple terms without discussing the process of how you want to achieve the result?

Comment: The result would be a function that builds an array of values from column B.  The values are restricted by having the same value in column A.

'E.g. Column A value = 1 myArray = (0,1,2)'
'Column B Value = 2 myArray = (4,5,6,7,8)'

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks

Comment: In your sample data, column A is in ascending sequence.  Will this be true of the real data?

Comment: Yes this will be true.  Although I might be able to find a way to change that if it makes a solution easier.

Comment: This is something which a normal `.Find` can help you. Or do you specifically want a UDF?

Comment: To be honest I was not aware of .Find.  I am self taught and have a ton of gaps.  Let me read up on that.  

Long story short, no it does not need to be a UDF.

Comment: FYI : http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 2):

think of an array as one row of an excel sheet, with the columns being the indexes. What you want to do you said was store values in said array. So you get your value, b, and you want to put that in the array.

what you want to do:

when declaring the array, declare it like `Dim myArrary() as Variant`
notice the brackets (not positive if they are required but its best practise.

that declares an empty array. Like an excel sheet with no columns. 
if you knew for A fact the array would have 5 values, you could declare:

`Dim myArrary(1 to 5) as Variant` that says, its an array with 5 indexes. (like an excel row with 5 columns)

the numbers, 1 to 5, those are the start and end index numbers. so, in that array, when reffering to the first spot,  you'd put `myArray(1)` the brackets like that are how you refer to specific indexes in the array. second spot would be myArray(2) 3rd myArray(3) 4th myArray(4) and 5th (the last spot) would be myArray(5).

You can declare themn like dim myarray(0 to 5) as variant, that means the first index would be myArray(0) - this array would have 6 spot - 0,1,2,3,4,5

So, in your code, you'd need a counter to keep track what iteration of the loop you were on and increment it like `counter = cojunter + 1` at the bottom of the loop. (it would increase each time the loop ran) then, replace the line that says `myArray = Array(B)` with `myArray(counter) = B`

so each time the loop runs, `B` will go into a spot in the array.

1 more thing,

because we dont know at the begginning how many spots the array will have, and we declare it empty: `dim myArray() as variant` you must redefine it after to have spaces before we can add anything. so, at the beginning of the loop, you wanna put `Redim Preserve MyArray(1 to counter)` this redefines your array as being from 1 to whatever your counter is at. since the counter increases by 1 each time, 1 space will be added to the array each time.

so basically,

replace `Dim myArrary as Variant` with  Dim myArrary() as Variant
add: `dim counter as long` up in the variables (name it whatever u want, just be consistant)

add `counter = 1` before the loop to initialize the counter

add `ReDim myArray(1 to counter)` in the loop, in the if statment (thus only adding the space if B was found

add `counter = counter + 1` at the end if the if, but again inside the is, thus only incrementing if a value for B is found

and change  `myArray = Array(B)` to `MyArray(counter) = B` in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that I created. Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim MyAr() As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim SearchString

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    SearchString = 2

    With ws
        '~~> Set this to your range
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A14")

        Set aCell = rng.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            '~~> Store the value from Col B in the array
            ReDim Preserve MyAr(n)
            MyAr(n) = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
            n = n + 1

            '~~> Find Next occurance
            Do
                Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    '~~> Store the value from Col B in the array
                    ReDim Preserve MyAr(n)
                    MyAr(n) = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
                    n = n + 1
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End With

    '~~> This will give you the results
    For n = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        Debug.Print MyAr(n)
    Next n
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, there's no simple concept of "adding an item to an array". You always have to declare beforehand how big you want the array to be, then you can work with the items in the array. While it's possible to write code that increases the size of an array by one element, this usually isn't the correct approach.

In this scenario, building the array will be a two-step process: first you need to count how many items you will be putting in your array, then you need to populate the array. In my example, `x` is the number you're searching for in column A.

```
Function MakeArray(x As Integer) As Variant
    Dim result() As Variant
    Dim result_count As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cursor As Range

    result_count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), x)

    ' size the array to how many elements we need, minus one
    ' because the array indexes start at zero
    ReDim result(result_count - 1)

    ' scan through the data and populate our array
    Set cursor = Range("A2:B2")
    i = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(cursor(1))
        If cursor(1) = x Then
             result(i) = cursor(2)
             i = i + 1
             If i > UBound(result) Then Exit Do
        End If
        Set cursor = cursor.Offset(1)
    Loop

    MakeArray = result
End Function
```

Comment: I do not agree with your first para :)

Comment: increasing the array by 1 every time the loop runs is just as acceptible to counting, then setting the size once.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Doesn't using `ReDim` a lot (i.e. inside a loop) slow down performance? If not, I've been misled!

Comment: @ARich: Seeing that ways even a loop slows down the code :) When you do not know the number of items then it is perfectly fine in using Redim inside a loop.

Comment: ReDim Preserve makes a new array and copies the entire array into the new array. It generates garbage and is a O(n) operation. If you have a lot of data it can cause performance issues.

Comment: I agree with what you said in the previous comment but I still do not agree with the first para completely. `there's no simple concept of "adding an item to an array"` How much more simpler can it get? `You always have to declare` Always? Not true again. :)

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, When you do not know the number of items then it is perfectly fine in using Redim Preserve or as a matter of fact a collection or a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, show me an example of using an array with declaring how big it is.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last comment. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I thought you were disagreeing with my assertion that you have to declare how big an array is before you can use it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me :) You can declare an array only if you know the number of items. If you do not know then using redim preserve is just fine.

Comment: In the above case, you were able to determine the size using `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), x)` but what if you actually don't know what the final size of the array would be then in that case what will you do? And hence my objection was specifically to the word `Always` in your statement `You always have to declare...` Hope you got what I am trying to say :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46461/discussion-between-tmdean-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Seems like you are facing some problems in chat?

Answer (score 0):

Might well not count as an answer, but without VBA, in C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(A3<>A2,IF(A1=A2,C1&","&B2,"("&B2)&")",IF(A1=A2,C1&","&B2,"("&B2))
```

then copy ColumnC and Paste Special Values over the top, filter to select does not contain `)` and delete visible should show:

ColumnA start of range
ColumnB end of range
ColumnC array